# inserting data in my sqlite database via iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am creating an iPhone application which makes use of sqlite database. I have one table in my database. Initially there are no rows in my table. I want that when I insert a new record via my iPhone simulator that record should be automatically updated to my database. How Could this be possible. Please anybody help me in solving this problem.

```
+ (void) getInitialDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath 
{
    SQLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sql = "select coffeeID, coffeeName from coffee";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                Coffee *coffeeObj = [[Coffee alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                coffeeObj.coffeeName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

                coffeeObj.isDirty = NO;

                [appDelegate.coffeeArray addObject:coffeeObj];
                [coffeeObj release];
            }
        }
    }
    else
        sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
}

+ (void) finalizeStatements 
{
    if (database) sqlite3_close(database);
        if (deleteStmt) sqlite3_finalize(deleteStmt);
            if (addStmt) sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
                if (detailStmt) sqlite3_finalize(detailStmt);
                    if (updateStmt) sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
                        }

- (id) initWithPrimaryKey:(NSInteger) pk 
{
    [super init];
    coffeeID = pk;

    coffeeImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    isDetailViewHydrated = NO;

    return self;
}

- (void) deleteCoffee 
{
    if(deleteStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "delete from Coffee where coffeeID = ?";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }

    //When binding parameters, index starts from 1 and not zero.
    sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStmt, 1, coffeeID);

    if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt)) 
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        sqlite3_reset(deleteStmt);
        }

- (void) addCoffee 
{
    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into Coffee(CoffeeName, Price) Values(?, ?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [coffeeName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 2, [price doubleValue]);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        else
            //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
            coffeeID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

            //Reset the add statement.
            sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
            }

- (void) hydrateDetailViewData 
{
    //If the detail view is hydrated then do not get it from the database.
    if(isDetailViewHydrated) return;

    if(detailStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "Select price, CoffeeImage from Coffee Where CoffeeID = ?";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &detailStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating detail view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }

    sqlite3_bind_int(detailStmt, 1, coffeeID);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) {

        //Get the price in a temporary variable.
        NSDecimalNumber *priceDN = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:sqlite3_column_double(detailStmt, 0)];

        //Assign the price. The price value will be copied, since the property is declared with "copy" attribute.
        self.price = priceDN;

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(detailStmt, 1) length:sqlite3_column_bytes(detailStmt, 1)]; 

        if(data == nil)
            NSLog(@"No image found.");
            else
                self.coffeeImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; 

                //Release the temporary variable. Since we created it using alloc, we have own it.
                [priceDN release];
    }
    else
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while getting the price of coffee. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        //Reset the detail statement.
        sqlite3_reset(detailStmt);

        //Set isDetailViewHydrated as YES, so we do not get it again from the database.
        isDetailViewHydrated = YES;
        }

- (void) saveAllData
{
    if(isDirty) 
    {
        if(updateStmt == nil) 
        {
            const char *sql = "update Coffee Set CoffeeName = ?, Price = ?, CoffeeImage = ? Where CoffeeID = ?";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                }

        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [coffeeName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_double(updateStmt, 2, [price doubleValue]);

        NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.coffeeImage);

        int returnValue = -1;
        if(self.coffeeImage != nil)
            returnValue = sqlite3_bind_blob(updateStmt, 3, [imgData bytes], [imgData length], NULL);
            else
                returnValue = sqlite3_bind_blob(updateStmt, 3, nil, -1, NULL);

                sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 4, coffeeID);

                if(returnValue != SQLITE_OK)
                    NSLog(@"Not OK!!!");

                    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
                        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

                        sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);

                        isDirty = NO;
                        }

    //Reclaim all memory here.
    [coffeeName release];
    coffeeName = nil;
    [price release];
    price = nil;

    isDetailViewHydrated = NO;
}

- (void)setCoffeeName:(NSString *)newValue 
{
    self.isDirty = YES;
    [coffeeName release];
    coffeeName = [newValue copy];
}

- (void)setPrice:(NSDecimalNumber *)newNumber 
{
    self.isDirty = YES;
    [price release];
    price = [newNumber copy];
}

- (void)setCoffeeImage:(UIImage *)theCoffeeImage 
{
    self.isDirty = YES;
    [coffeeImage release];
    coffeeImage = [theCoffeeImage retain];
}
```

Comment: When you say you want the record updated to your database, do you mean a separate database than the sqlite within the app (a syncing question) or are you just having problems inserting rows in the sqlite db?

Comment: i am having problems inserting rows in the sqlite db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as I see you have this function `+(void) finalizeStatements;` where you close your DB and finalize your prepared queries.
First of all, you don't call this function from anywhere. Anyway if you are somehow calling this function, the code from is not correct, because you should first finalize all statements and only after that close the connection.
Read the documentation of **sqlite3_close** and **sqlite3_finalize**. What the documentation says about **sqlite3_close**:
**Applications must [sqlite3_finalize | finalize] all [prepared statements] and [sqlite3_blob_close | close] all [BLOB handles] associated with the [sqlite3] object prior to attempting to close the object.** 
If that won't help you, try to finalize statements at the end of each method you prepare it.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the database variable you've opened in getInitialDataToDisplay is still available when you try to addCoffee. Why don't you close that connection, and open a new one at the beginning of addCoffee (and close that when it completes)